# Nest.js authentication using typeORM

Tags: typescript, passport.js, nestjs, typeorm

I have created a working server with connection to the database, with a simple `get` request that works.
i followed https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication this guide.

when running the server and trying to perform a `get` request from a guarded route, i get `Cannot read property 'challenge' of undefined`. 
**user.controller.ts**

```
import { Controller, Get, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { User } from './user.entity';
import { AuthGuard, PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Controller()
export class UserController {
  constructor(
    private readonly userService: UserService)
    {}

  @Get('user')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard())
  findAll(): Promise<User[]> {
   return this.userService.findAll();
  }

  @Get('users')
  find(): Promise<User[]> {
   return this.userService.findAll();
  }
}
```

**auth.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { HttpStrategy } from './http.strategy';
import { UserModule } from 'database/entities/user/user.module';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
const passportModule = PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'bearer' });

@Module({
  imports: [
    passportModule,
    UserModule],
    providers: [AuthService, HttpStrategy],
    exports: [passportModule],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

also when running the server i get a warning `[AuthGuard] In order to use "defaultStrategy", please, ensure to import PassportModule in each place where AuthGuard() is being used. Otherwise, passport won't work correctly.`

Comment: Do you import PassportModule in the module UserModule?

Comment: You need to import PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'bearer' }), in 
 each module wherever AuthGuard() is used.